# example on solve implicit function

Tags: implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

I was trying to find some examples of explicitly solving implicit functions. However, most I found was about implicit differentiation.
For example, if we have a function $u(x,t)$, the implicit form says
$$
u=\frac{1}{1+ut}
$$

How can we directly invert this and got the explicit form for $u(x,t)$?

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed time $t$, we can write the equation as

$$u(x)(1 + u(x)*t) = 1$$

$$\implies u + u^2t = 1$$

This is a quadratic in $u$, solutions given by

$$u(x) = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4t}}{2t}$$

Now if we know $x(t)$ we can get the desired parametric form - usually this sort of problem is to find a quantity along a particular curve where we would have more information on the relationship of $x$ and $t$

Comment: that's what I tried before. however, there's also an initial condition given at t=0 which doesn't make sense if we do quadratic because t is on the denominator. u=u(x,t) not just u(x).